# How to verify an 'int?' parameter in C# to avoid exceptions in controller page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a class which validate different inputs.

In Controller, I have a simple ActionResult method type.

```
 public ActionResult Detail( int? id ) {
           ViewData["value"] = _something.GetValueById( id );
           return View();
        }
```

If you navigate to `http://localhost/Home/Detail/3` then the controller return the View where it shows available values by id (it is integer) from model.

If ID is null then the controller redirect me to all values.

If you change the ID route (like `http://localhost/Home/Detail/3fx`) to different data type then the controller returns red page. (with exception)

I want to check that ID is int or not to avoid red page error (with list of exceptions).

I saw that `isNaN` is only for double data type.

Sorry if my question is annoying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a [route constraint](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs) to force the `ID` parameter to be a valid integer.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyRoute",
    "Home/Details/{id}",
    new {controller="Home", action="Details",  id = UrlParameter.Optional},
    new {id = @"\d+" }
);
```

Comment: While this will skip his route, it will return a resource not found error won't it?  Wouldn't he be able to resolve it by changing `Detail( int? id )` to `Detail( string id )` and doing the check there?

Comment: What happens if you write : abcde as ID route? Will throw an exception ? I want if you write `http://localhost/Home/Detail/apple` then the page will returns same with one which ID doesn't exists.

Comment: @DMoses: I wrote a javascript function which provide an integer value to Detail function

Comment: @DMoses isn't resource not found more correct approach here, Just a doubt ?

Comment: If I understand you well, you want to set the `ID` as null when a string is being passed as parameter? That's the default behavior (without constraint applied).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your example correctly, then you can't check the type of the ID before it gets to your Detail function, correct?

In this case I would change your "int? id" to "object id". Then you can check the type of object in the function itself. Something like...

```
    public ActionResult Detail(object id)
    {
        int myID;
        if (int.TryParse(id.ToString(), out myID))
        {
            ViewData["value"] = _discipline.GetValueById(id);
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
string Str = textBox1.Text.Trim();
double Num;
bool isNum = double.TryParse(Str, out Num);
if (isNum)
    MessageBox.Show(Num.ToString());
else
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid number");
```

check this link
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/84990ad2-5046-472b-b103-f862bfcd5dbc/

Comment: I have no string. Only `int?`